# Letterspacing doesn't work with specific double letters

Tags: css, google-fonts

I need to implement a design for a webpage which includes Googles Webfont called "*Abril Fatface*" and some letterspacing.

This is where I found some strange behavior.

The letters `t` and `f` seem to ignore the letterspace setting, but only if they occur behind each other. They work as expected if they are between other letters, and it only seems to happen with `t` and `f`.

Does anybody know why this happens?

I tried this with the browsers default font which is Segoe or Arial, I'm not sure, and it seems to work fine there. Is this intended and there is a reason I don't know to remove the letterspacing especially there? Or is it a webfont bug?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface');
.fatface {
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface', serif;
}

.wide-text {
  font-size: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 70px;
}

.small {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="wide-text">
  <div class="fatface">botottle</div>
  <div>botottle</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="small">
  <div class="fatface">
    aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii jj kk ll mm nn oo pp qq rr ss tt uu vv ww xx yy zz
  </div>
  <div>
    aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii jj kk ll mm nn oo pp qq rr ss tt uu vv ww xx yy zz
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! Is there any way to force the letter-spacing? I don't think, that this looks good at all.

Comment: These letters are combined into one glyph, and you can not put “spacing between” _one single_ item of anything :-) You would need to use a font without such ligature features to begin with, or specifically disable the feature using CSS (see CodeBoyCode’s answer, but you might have to check browser support.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is ligatures - everything looked fine when I tested it.

```
* {
font-variant-ligatures: none;
}
```

Should probably do the trick (or replace the wildcard as necessary)

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware of that. Thank you very much! Even works in IE11 :)

Comment: No worries @MatthiasSeifert - please mark answer as correct :)

Comment: I am allowed to do this in 4 minutes ;)